# Adding multiple youtube playlists to site just like youtube has em

Tags: youtube, web, playlist

[this is desired output for site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCVUI.png)

this is how youtube displays multiple playlist...how can I add this just like they have it to my site AND to linkedin profile?

embedding the share html link just brings in playlist but it does not display properly....I need it to appear exactly like it does in attached pic???

Answer (score 0):

Linking to your LinkedIn profile, I have not tried. So perhaps someone else can tell you.
As to having a section like the one you showed to be on your own site is doable.

Firstly you will need to collect the [playlist ID's](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists/list) that you are going to use.
Then you will need to get the video ID's from the video's in each [Playlist](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list).
This can be done with the [API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/).

As to the displaying it like on youtube, you will need to do that yourself with one or more combination of table's, div's and CSS. Then With the information you grabbed in the APi, populate it.

Best to do it in a loop so as to be done all at the same time. Then put it to the page where you require it to be.